# Compiling bfx-cpp-api - Byte datatype undeclared

Tags: c++, gnu, crypto++

So I am looking to compile this project https://github.com/MMquant/bfx-cpp-api using the example code. I have included the cryptopp file that was suggested in the read me. It is found here: https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.

I am using Ubutnu version 17.10 and the GNU compiler.

Here's how I am compiling:

```
g++ example.cpp BitfinexAPI.cpp BitfinexAPI.hpp  -Icryptopp -I.  -o a -w -std=c++17
```

It seems strange that BitFinex would support broken code so I am fairly sure that the issue must be something that I am doing.

The errors I am getting are related to line 936 where the datatype 'byte' is not declared. My prediction is that I am missing a header file somewhere but any help would be appreciated.

---

```
$ g++ example.cpp BitfinexAPI.cpp BitfinexAPI.hpp  -Icryptopp -I.  -o a -w -std=c++17
BitfinexAPI.cpp: In static member function ‘static int BitfinexAPI::getBase64(const string&, std::__cxx11::string&)’:
BitfinexAPI.cpp:936:5: error: ‘byte’ was not declared in this scope
     byte buffer[1024] = {};
     ^~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:936:5: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from ../cryptopp/seckey.h:9:0,
                 from ../cryptopp/hmac.h:9,
                 from BitfinexAPI.cpp:37:
../cryptopp/config.h:222:23: note:   ‘CryptoPP::byte’
 typedef unsigned char byte;
                       ^~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:940:9: error: ‘buffer’ was not declared in this scope
         buffer[i] = content[i];
         ^~~~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:940:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘setbuffer’
         buffer[i] = content[i];
         ^~~~~~
         setbuffer
BitfinexAPI.cpp:943:21: error: ‘buffer’ was not declared in this scope
     StringSource ss(buffer, content.length(), true, new Base64Encoder( new StringSink(encoded), false));
                     ^~~~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:943:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘setbuffer’
     StringSource ss(buffer, content.length(), true, new Base64Encoder( new StringSink(encoded), false));
                     ^~~~~~
                     setbuffer
BitfinexAPI.cpp: In static member function ‘static int BitfinexAPI::getHmacSha384(const string&, const string&, std::__cxx11::string&)’:
BitfinexAPI.cpp:963:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     SecByteBlock byteKey((const byte*)key.data(), key.size());
                                 ^~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:963:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
     SecByteBlock byteKey((const byte*)key.data(), key.size());
                           ^~~~~
BitfinexAPI.cpp:963:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
```

Comment: Well. I have seen [std::byte](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is accepted as type in C++17 and searching a little bit, the [C++1z Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) accepts byte as type from GCC 7. So your version of g++ is lower than 7 could be the reason why byte is not accepted. Which version do you use of  g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's how I am compiling:
>
> ```
> g++ example.cpp BitfinexAPI.cpp BitfinexAPI.hpp  -Icryptopp -I.  -o a -w -std=c++17
> ```
>
> It seems strange that BitFinex would support broken code so I am
>   fairly sure that the issue must be something that I am doing.
>
> The errors I am getting are related to line 936 where the datatype
>   'byte' is not declared. My prediction is that I am missing a header
>   file somewhere but any help would be appreciated.

@kabanus identified the problem.

Crypto++ used to provide a `byte` in the global C++ namespace. It was there for two reasons. First, it was a convenience item on Linux. You could use `byte` instead of `CryptoPP::byte`. Second, it avoided compiler errors on Windows. Microsoft SDK's provide a `byte` in the global namespace, and if we put a `byte` at `CryptoPP::byte` then compile errors resulted from ambiguous definitions.

C++17 came along and offered a `std::byte`; see [P0298R0, A byte type definition](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r0.pdf). The global Crypto++ `byte` broke Linux when folks used a `using namespace std`. And it completely broke Microsoft because Microsoft SDK's provides a global `byte`. Ironically, the authors of P0298R0 work for Microsoft.

Crypto++ placing a `byte` in the global namespace was a C++ No-No. We got away with it for years, but it jumped up and bit us in C++17. We moved it into our namespace where it belongs. The check-in occurred at [Commit 00f9818b5d8e](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/00f9818b5d8e), which happened after 5.6.5 was released and prior to 6.0 release.

Looking at the source for `BitfinexAPI.cpp`, this is probably the solution... open `BitfinexAPI.cpp`, and add the following at the top of the file:

```
// CRYPTOPP_NO_GLOBAL_BYTE signals byte is at CryptoPP::byte
#if defined(CRYPTOPP_NO_GLOBAL_BYTE)
  using CryptoPP::byte;
#endif
```

Also see [std::byte](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Std::byte) on the Crypto++ wiki. We took the time to document it because of all the problems `std::byte`, Microsoft's global `byte` and our `byte` definitions are going to cause.

---

Related, you don't need to specify the C++ header on the command line. The compile error is due to the changes detailed above. All you need is:

```
g++ -std=c++17 example.cpp BitfinexAPI.cpp -I. ./cryptopp/libcryptopp.a -o example.exe
```

This assumes a directory structure of:

```
- bfx-api/
  |
  +- cryptopp/
```

The `cryptopp/libcryptopp.a` is a convenient way to sidestep those stupid Linux path problems that have existed for years. You link against the static archive which means you don't need a library at runtime.

---

Now open in the BFX issue tracker: [Crypto++ byte change at Crypto++ 6.0](https://github.com/MMquant/bfx-cpp-api/issues/2). It should help the project engineer around the changes.

Comment: Good clarification of your motives.

Answer (score 2):

A bit tricky but I (think?) found it. `byte` is defined in the `cryptopp` code at:

https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h

line 222. So I'm guessing the `config.h` on your system is non-existent, probably because you didn't properly install the header. A common problem is having the library

```
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++
```

but missing the developer files (specifically the headers)

```
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev
```

I'm not 100% about the package names (Debian user), should be close though.

**Good catch from JTejedor**:

Seems like the crypto guys placed a namespace around their definitions so as to not conflict with `std::byte`. You may want to add a `CryptoPP::` to the byte definition in bfx (line 936), and if that works open a bug to the guys over there (or request a pull).

Comment: Due the standard declaration of byte in C++17, Cryptopp include the byte declaration inside its namespace instead of global namespace (line 212 in your config.h link). I think maybe MMQuant does not update this byte declaration in line 936 to be declared inside the new namespace

Comment: Good catch, you may be very well correct. I'll update.

Comment: How I got the files to compile required a few modifications of the original github file. All instances of byte need to be changed to unsigned char. Which another user suggested but the comment was deleted for some reason.

kabanus was correct in suggesting that I use

sudo apt-get install libcrypto++ and sudo apt-get install libcrypto++

The working compile message is g++ example.cpp BitfinexAPI.cpp BitfinexAPI.hpp -lcurl -lcrypto++ -lcryptopp -o a -w -std=c++14

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @Jerome I suggested it and deleted - the reason is the original coders wanted to use a type specifically defined in Crypto. If they decide to change the `typedef` one day you would be screwed (though this is unlikely, and today it is indeed `char`). At first I though it was just an error by `bfx` and suggested the `char`, but they knew what they were doing.